# Use of TLS 1.0 and 1.1 with DNN and 2sxc

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9, tls1.0, tls1.1

We will soon be attempting to turn off TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on our servers that host our DNN websites. Before we do so, we thought we'd ask if anyone knew of any reason that the 2sxc module might not function correctly after those are turned off? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be no issues at all. Also, the config that does that is usually fairly easy to enable and disable, so easy to test on a weekend.

But again, nothing about TLS has anything to do with 2sxc. Main thing to test is that your SMTP connection is working after you disable stuff.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you!